# How can I use webdriver manager in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium and have an error after update to chrome browser 75 to 76. 
the error is below:

```
[2019-08-10 16:11:52] local.ERROR: sendKeysToActiveElement
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11- 
14T08:25:53'
```

My stackoverflow post about my problem finally got a solution, but it is for Python, so I can't apply it to my code, and I don't know how to apply it to PHP's laravel.

The solution I got is below:

> You can use below code instead of System.setProperty code and add 
>       WebDriverManager 3 version jar file in your build path,irrespective of 
>       browser version, it will work properly.
>
> ```
> WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
> DesiredCapabilities dcap = new DesiredCapabilities();
> dcap.setCapability("pageLoadStrategy", "none");
> ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
> options.merge(dcap);
> driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
> driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
> ```

I'm using laravel and facebook webdriver and downloaded "webdrivermanager-3.6.2" from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/3.6.2).

Would you show me simple example for php?

I know this problem is very easy, but it is not easy for me.

Comment: There is equivalent solution in php https://github.com/peridot-php/webdriver-manager . Not sure if that project  is maintained  or not. Good luck

Comment: you could always update the webdrivers manually.  Btw, your error seems related to this (change to the driver concerning w3c):  https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5261